# show date and time separately in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, time

Trying to show the time and date separately in Swift 3 and both fields are returning nil. I'm receiving the date as a string thats in the standard Date() format.

```
public func formatDateForAbandonTicket(_ dte: String) -> String {
    print(dte)
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let t = timeFormatter.date(from: dte)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d/MM/YYYY"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
    let d = dateFormatter.date(from: dte)
    print()
    print(t)
    print()
    print(d)
    return "\(d)" + "     " + "\(t)"
}
```

I get a nil response from both d & t. The parameter does contain the right date "2017-11-14 16:36:29 +0000".

Thanks

Comment: Step back a bit. How was the string `dte` created? Did you start with a `Date` object or was that string obtained as-is from some API?

Comment: Its from an API source

Comment: `dte` is a `String` and you're trying to calculate time duration using `dte`? Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you need to first convert `dte` to a `Date` and to do that, you need to specify a format that matches the complete date string. You only need one `Date`, not two.

And there is no reason to create two separate strings just to combine them back into one.

```
public func formatDateForAbandonTicket(_ dte: String) -> String {
    print(dte)
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    if let date = df.date(from: dte) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d/MM/yyyy     HH:mm"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return dateStr
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Also note that you are converting the result to a time in UTC time instead of the user's locale time. That's fine if that is what you need, just make sure it makes sense to the user.